# Google API Client Library giving PHP error

Tags: php, android, composer-php, google-signin

I installed the Google API Client Library on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 using Composer and I am following up their guidance on their webpage.

Whenever, I need to verify a G suite account, I am including this code:

require_once `vendor/autoload.php`; But it is throwing a `500 internal error`.

The details of the error are

`<br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in <b>/var/www/html/php/insert.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />`

I ran the `find . -name autoload.php` command, and found out that the file is located at `./vendor/autoload.php` and because of that I am using the `require_once('../../../../vendor/autoload.php');` as it maps to the right path. Still, I get the error above.

I tried using `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'` as suggesed in the answer by Alex below, but I get the following error now.

`<br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/php/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in <b>/var/www/html/php/insert.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />`

I need that file for the Library to run.

Comment: Please improve your question with a name of the library you are using, as it is written in composer.json, and add actual error from the log. 500 is a generic serverside error which tells nothing about nature of the error.

Comment: If removing the line fixes the problem - remove the line.

Comment: but does the library still work ?

Comment: you said "the code works fine", I get it as it does what you expect.

Comment: Alex, my bad. I updated the question.

Comment: Mind updating the question as of my initial comment? At current edition it falls into "why isn't this code working?" offtopic.

Comment: Alex, there is no further info in the error logs.

Comment: Server logs. Or add  `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` at the top of your script to let it send the error message to the client. And surely you know the canonical name of the library.

Comment: @AlexBlex check update

Comment: The error says there is no `autoload` file you are requiring. Either you did not run `composer install` to generate the file, or messed with path location. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `composer.json` is located in the same directory as `insert.php`, the `require` line should be like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'
```

`__DIR__` is translated to absolute path of the directory where current script is located, and `'/vendor/autoload.php'` is a relative path from the directory to the `autoload.php`.

Comment: If your `find` results with `./vendor/autoload.php`, why do you use `../../../../vendor/autoload.php` ? It makes no sense to me. Please use the code in the answer, I have updated it with some explanations.

Comment: so what `.` in `find` refers to? I assumed you ran it from `/var/www/html/php/` where your php files are located but apparently it is not true.

Comment: the file `autoload.php` is found at `/root/vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: Okay, I won't comment on the choice of the location for vendors. Check your httpd/php user has access to the file, and include it with absolute path then: `require_once "/root/vendor/autoload.php";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137542/discussion-between-tony9099-and-alex-blex).